# The number in my variable is not being detected

Tags: python-3.7

Ok, so i'm making a mini-game sort of thing that generates a random number, whatever number it generates determines which horse has won the race. you can bet at the start and if your bet is right, you win. But my problem is when I get my bet right it always says 'Your bet lost!' I've been searching and can't find out the problem.

```
print ("Welcome to the Horse Race!")
print ("The horses racing are, Horse 1, Horse 2, Horse 3 and Horse 4.")
print ("who are you betting on? (Type the horse number)")
bet = input()
int(bet)
print ("The Horses are racing! who will win?")
import time
time.sleep(1)
from random import randrange

winner = randrange(1, 4)
int(winner)
if winner == 1:
     print("Horse 1 has won!")
     if bet == 1:
      print("Your bet won!")

elif winner == 2:
     print("Horse 2 has won!")
     if bet == 2:
          print("Your bet won!")

elif winner == 3:
    print("Horse 3 has won!")
    if bet == 3:
         print("Your bet won!")

elif winner == 4:
    print("Horse 4 has won!")
    if bet == 4:
         print("You bet won!")

if bet != winner:
     print("Your bet lost! Sorry!")
```

Comment: `int(bet)` does not make `bet` an integer. Use `bet = int(bet)`.

Answer (score 1):

You're casting your `bet` from a string to an integer, but you're not saving the casted value.

Change `int(bet)` to `bet = int(bet)` and it should work.

Note that this also applies to `int(winner)`, although the cast isn't necessary since `randrange()` already returns an integer.

Comment: You're right, that one has the same issue, but it's less important since `randrange()` returns an integer: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/random.html#functions-for-integers

Comment: I strongly suggest to mention this in your answer.